# Событие рендера JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, события, render

Есть ли в JS событие, которое вызывается при каждом рендере страницы (т.е. много раз в секунду)?

Comment: я думаю, вы имели ввиду в API браузеров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.requestAnimationFrame( callack )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Вызывается примерно 60 раз в секунду. Переданная функция сама должна вызывать frame с самим собой, чтобы оно зациклилось:

```js
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let left = 0, rotate = 0, dir = 1;

loop();
function loop( current_time_ms ) {
  // console.log( current_time_ms );
  animate();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

/***/

function animate() {
  left += dir * 5;
  rotate += dir * 5;
  demo.style.transform = `translateX(${ left }px) rotate(${ rotate }deg)`;
  
  if( left >= 400 || left <= 0 ) dir *= -1;
}
```

```css
#demo { position: absolute; top: 40px; height: 50px; width: 50px; background: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```